# Outputting a Histogram Using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an array that I would like to output as a histogram. Each index in the array would represent a column and the value would represent the size. An example array:

arr[0] = 5
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 1
arr[3] = 6
arr[4] = 9

Would it be possible to output this array into a histogram somehow? Maybe through Excel?

Comment: Look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198703, it may help you.You can record a macro and see the generated code, it also may help you how to create the histogram.

Comment: @ehh Sorry for the late reply, this worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get help from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198703) link for Excel automation via VB Script.

Use a [Macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-2841ba85-9da6-4bd7-93a4-0da90844f283) to get generated code on how to create an histogram in excel.

Following a very basic example of a column chart using Record Macro:

[image]

This is the code generated which you can use to write your own code:

```
Sub Macro2()
'   Macro2 Macro
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:B6")
End Sub
```